# Keys are pressed many times in CS:GO

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, linux

I installed CS:GO on my computer, and when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>E</kbd> in game, it looks like the key presses many times per second instead just holding. So I can't select players in Tab-menu and defuse bombs.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using a wireless keyboard? Do you have this behavior in any other games?

Comment: No I use wired keyboard, similar behaviour I saw only in one windows game(Infernal) under wine, and then I fixed it by installing older wine version